# Flutter project is not running on physical device

Tags: flutter

When I make a build of flutter project on windows(chrome) it run successfully but when i run on my phone it gives this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      tools Android SDK Tools
      build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
  The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Users\Cantt)


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I installed the Andriod SDK platform 32 and 31. please help how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open android studio and go to SDK manager
2. Check SDK platforms API level 28, 29, 30
3. Then apply and ok

Then

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get 
flutter run
```

Comment: I'm trying to install 30 but it gives me installation failed error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on Android Studio.

Help>Find Action and then search for each and select:

1. clean project
2. rebuild project
3. Invalidate caches

Then restart Android Studio.

This should fix the issue.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Did the error change?